# Failed to Send Host log on ERROR on Ubuntu In Virtual Box maybe due to less root disk space

Tags: virtualbox

I know that there are similiar questions , but none of them seems to resolve the Issue. Basically, a quite few days back, there was this notification coming on my ubuntu VM that there is a little root disk space left.But, now when I am trying to open my Ubuntu on Virtual Box, I am getting the following error ERROR: failed to send host log me,in black screen. I think it is due to the less root disk space notification which was showing earlier.

Any help on fixing this will really be appreciated,thanks[image]

Comment: WHat is the result of command `df -h /var`?

Comment: @RomeoNinov it isnt letting type anything there

Comment: Boot from rescue CD and check the free disk space. Or try to do ssh to the machine.